# Is it possible to dockerize an existing flask+nginx project?

Tags: docker, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I have a working webpage.

- It is hosted on an rpi.
- Backend is using flask and SQLite.
- Python is using a venv and the server is nginx.
- These are connected with uWSGI.
- Source code is in github.

I have heard that a docker can add an extra layer of security.
Is it possible to add this project to a docker container (without breaking functionality) after the page is up and running?

What changes must be done if possible?

Comment: This is a very general question. No one can easily tell you how to dockerise your application without more information. You would be best doing some research on docker yourself to get an understanding of how it works and then try and apply it to your own application.

Comment: _heard that a docker can add an extra layer of security_. Not true. Simply putting Docker there doesn't add security. It might expose more issues as Docker is insecure, by default

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's perfectly possible. But even though you should be able to host it in your RPI, I don't think it's worth the effort.

What you will need:

0. [Install docker in RPI device](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/docker-on-raspberry-pi)
1. [Write a `Dockerfile`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) containing the instructions to setup and run the application
2. [Build the image](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) from your `Dockerfile`
3. [Run the image](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/) in your RPI's docker